# How to close the input stream of an IronPython engine executing a script?

Tags: .net, ironpython, stream

I am creating an IronPython engine more or less like so:

```
var engine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine();                
var scope = engine.CreateScope();

// my implementation of System.IO.Stream
var stream = new ScriptOutputStream(engine);
engine.Runtime.IO.SetOutput(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
engine.Runtime.IO.SetErrorOutput(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
engine.Runtime.IO.SetInput(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

var script = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(source, SourceCodeKind.Statements);
script.Execute(scope);
```

The variable `source` is a string with following contents (python statements):

```
import code
code.interact(None, None, 
        {
            '__name__' :  '__console__', 
            '__doc__'  :   None, 
        })
```

The stream is being hosted on a windows form. When that form closes, I want the interpreter to quit. Obviously, I tried closing the stream in the `Read` method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Read from the _inputBuffer, block until a new line has been entered...
    /// </summary>
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {

        if (_gui.IsDisposed)
        {
            return 0; // msdn says this indicates the stream is closed
        }

        while (_completedLines.Count < 1)
        {
            // wait for user to complete a line
            Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        var line = _completedLines.Dequeue();
        return line.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }
```

The member variable `_completedLines` holds a queue of `MemoryStream` objects representing lines the user has entered so far. `_gui` is a reference to the windows form - when it is disposed, I somehow want the IronPython engine to stop executing `code.interact()`.

Returnin `0` from the `Read` method does not work (`Read` is just called again). Raising one of the exceptions from the [documentation of Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx) does not work either: It does stop execution of the interpreter, but the IDE breaks inside the `Read` method :(

I have also tried returning `^Z` (0x1a) and `^D` (0x04) in `Read`'s buffer, as these are used on the console to quit the interpreter, but that doesn't work at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a second look to figure out what you wanted, but this looks like a bug in IronPython. `code.interact` expects an EOFError to be raised from the `raw_input` builtin to signal that it's time for the loop to end, but IronPython doesn't do that - it just returns an empty string. This is IronPython [issue #22140](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=22140).

You could try throwing an EndOfStreamException, which converts to EOFError. That might be enough to trick it.

Comment: I've tried engine.Runtime.Shutdown() - it doesn't work :( I'll try again, though...

Comment: I tried throwing SystemExitException - this still causes the IDE to break inside the custom stream class (unhandled user exception), even though the caller of the script.Excecute() *does* handle the error...

Comment: I rewrote my answer to better address your question - not sure it's the answer you want to hear, though.

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to work - i.e. it still breaks into the IDE, but when run standalone, IronPython seems to recognize the EndOfStreamException!